# Actuator checks for binders fail

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

When I run [kafka-streams-word-count](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-word-count) example.

Actuator's health check fail
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "components": {
    "binders": {
      "status": "DOWN",
      "components": {
        "globalktable": {
          "status": "DOWN",
          "details": {
            "No topic information available": "Kafka broker is not reachable"
          }
        },
        "kstream": {
          "status": "DOWN",
          "details": {
            "No topic information available": "Kafka broker is not reachable"
          }
        },
        "ktable": {
          "status": "DOWN",
          "details": {
            "No topic information available": "Kafka broker is not reachable",
            "error": "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread is not accepting new calls."
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 250685575168,
        "free": 25818120192,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

I run kafka locally this way:

docker run -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 -e EULA="https://dl.lenses.io/d/?id=..." --rm -p 3030:3030 -p 9092:9092 lensesio/box

Comment: This was a bug in the binder which is now addressed through the PR that you submitted. Thank you!

Comment: yep, I didn't know that in the beginning, I waited for a few hours and then checked the code. thanks for merging the PR :)